# Returning List<string> from Linq query returns query syntax not values

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below code to return a list of strings.

```
public List<string> Top5CodesForToday()
{
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    var resultList = new List<string>();

    using (var db = new PillowContext())
    {
        var qry = (from d in db.DownTimes
            where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateTime) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(date)
            group d by new {d.Code}
            into g
            let total = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
            orderby total descending
            let top5 = g.Take(5).ToList()
            select new {g.Key.Code, Total = total});

        foreach (var item in qry)
        {
            int x = item.Code;
            var results = from r in db.DownTimeCodes
                          where r.Code == x
                          select r.Description;
            resultList.Add(results.ToString());
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

When I look at the contents of returnList I am seeing the correct number of items however each item is made up of the actual query syntax, not the data itself. I have seen this before and usually solve it by doing .ToList() however I am unsure how I could change my code to solve this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that when you are calling `ToString` the query is not executed yet, so essentially you are calling `ToString` on a `IQueryable` object, receiving the query instead of results. You need to call something to execute the query.

You can call `ToList()` still:

```
var results = (from r in db.DownTimeCodes
              where r.Code == x
              select r.Description).ToList();
resultList.AddRange(results);
```

Or, if you expect just one result, call `FirstOrDefault()`/`SingleOrDefault()`:

```
var results = (from r in db.DownTimeCodes
              where r.Code == x
              select r.Description).FirstOrDefault();
resultList.Add(results);
```

Comment: +1 There's no null check in the OP's code, so I'll wager that a call to `.First()` would be a better match in this case.

Comment: @ChristofferLette, not sure if this is an option at all, just added it for completeness. Name of the variable `results` hints that OP expects not one but several records

Comment: Correct, @Andrei. I'm just guessing, and I'm basing my guess on the fact that the OP is calling `.ToString()` on the `results`. If `results` is a list, `.ToString()` wouldn't normally be of much use.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, as simple as that. I have another problem now to due to running another query whilst iterating through the results from another query but that isn't related to the original question. I will mark as answer as soon as I have fixed that problem and tested

Comment: @Jimsan, just guessing of course, but it seems you can solve your another problem with calling another `ToList` for `qry` before the `foreach`.

Comment: Spot on again @Andrei. Added the extra ToList() and looped through that and everything is now working fine. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ToString()` on `List<>`. As default for most complex types, it just writes out type name not the data.

This line

```
resultList.Add(results.ToString());
```

should be changed to

```
resultList.AddRange(results);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will actually solve the OP's problem of getting rid of the "query syntax" in the results. I guess that what s/he wants to know is how to *materialize* the query.

Comment: OP explains that he got the right number of rows, but it contains only type names. So, the problems lies in filling of `resultList`. In sample provided both queries will be materialized - first by `foreach`, second - by adding items to `resultList`.

Comment: Ah... now I see what you did! And I didn't notice the switch to `AddRange` at first either.